What are the practical implications of interpreting the topology of compact Lie groups through first-order logic?
I have been studying the paper "Some Model Theory on Compact Lie Groups" (link to paper), and I had some questions regarding the paper.
From my reading, the main result appears to state that if a Lie group $G$ is both simple and centerless, then every statement about the topology of $G$ is logically equivalent to some statement expressible in the language of group theory within first-order logic (FOL).
This leads me to my question:

What are the potential benefits or applications of translating topological statements about such Lie groups into first-order group-theoretic statements?

I understand that topological structures are not first-order definable in general, so this equivalence seems significant. Could this result simplify certain proofs or provide new insights into compact Lie groups by leveraging the framework of FOL? Are there theoretical questions about compact Lie groups that become more transparent or easier to address using this approach? The result itself is very beautiful in its own right, but it also seems as though it could provide other benefits

I'm not really an expert on this particular area, but the fact that compact lie groups are (trivially) definable in the expansion of the real field by bounded analytic functions, which is (nontrivially) o-minimal means that we can use the (considerable) machinery of o-minimality for them. See also Pillay's conjecture (a theorem for a while now, due to Conversano I think) that you can actually recover the compact real lie group from a group definable in an o-minimal expansion of the reals. So in some sense, the "real" compact lie groups are properly extended by the definable category.

Mind, the result is not just about expansions of reals, but any ordered (necessarily real closed) field, which can give you weird groups defined using infinitésimals e.g., but this is probably not relevant to classical lie theory.
